# Blazor Wasm Takes For ever to load

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I am trying to investigate why first-time users have to wait SOOOO long for our website to download.|

We are using blazer wasm, without AOT (Ahead of time complication).

We have optimised all of our uses to minimise the number of file downloads.

So If I open ou site with Incognito mode and delete all cache.   (I'm on a fibre line at the office)

It takes:
[image]

So it takes over 3 minutes to load a website on a Fibre line, now our customers who are typically on a slow 3G link it basically doesn't work.

But what bothers me is each of these files is so small, why does each one take so long?  In a java script site, you are also loading loads of files and scripts etc from the server and it doesn't take this long.

Here are some examples of file downloading:
[image]

Why on earth would it take over 2 minutes to download such a tiny file?

I feel like there must be an issue on our server or something?

Obviously once a lot of these are cached and you refresh, it loads fairly quickly.

Has anyone else had this issue with blazor Wasm?.

Comment: Can you tell me what life-cycle hook you are using, is it OnInitializeAsync?

Comment: `slow 3G link` there's your problem. It's not just that 3G is actually being disabled across countries. Carriers put emphasis on their 4G networks for years, de-emphasizing 3G (ie less hardware). Which isn't just slower, it's also less resilient to noise because it uses fewer channels.

Comment: There are things that can make this worse though. For example, if you *don't* use HTTPS, you're not using HTTP/2 and its concurrent file downloads. What does your network tab look like? Is it a cascade of downloads or several concurrent downloads? If you don't use HTTPS, each file will have to be downloaded individually.

Comment: The screenshot also shows files that shouldn't be sent to the client at all, like Microsoft.Build.dll, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp etc. These should have been removed during publishing. How is this application published? How did these files end up in the `publish` folder?

Comment: I'm with @Henk on this one.  How fast is the dev/test system?   You haven't got this far developing with those sort of lags.   Build the standard WASM template and test using that.  There is something else happening here.

Comment: This sort of load time seems to be on publishing only, Dev environment is local to local so no network latency and it loads really fast.

I also thought that there was way to many asp,net looking files being downloaded. 

In the networks tab it seems to be like they where all initiated in parallel but it very much looks to be sequential.  Maybe it appears that way cause there so many files and its actually just doing 10 concurrently at a time.

Answer (score 0):

in .net 6 blazor wasm Has many issues with AOT mode
something as : slower startUp, big dlls and dotnet.wasm, very slow in low-end devices such as mobile phones.
you can see and read more about this in : [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/69797)
in .net 7 blazor wasm is very very faster than .net 6.

Comment: To my knowledge, all those issues come when you DO enable AOT.

We do not have AOT enabled for that exact reason.